# Property 'getCoordinates' does not exist on type 'Geometry'.ts(2339)

Tags: openlayers

I want to get coordinates from route but its giving error
`route.getCoordinates()` showing error

> Property 'getCoordinates' does not exist on type 'Geometry'.ts(2339)

```
var currentPath = [[- 122.52420998649377, 37.93487461785696], [- 122.52445351796212, 37.93545754807002], [- 122.52500075336911, 37.93561402033367]];
        var polyline = new Polyline({
            factor: 1e6
        }).writeGeometry(new LineString(currentPath));

        const route = new Polyline({
            factor: 1e6,
        }).readGeometry(polyline, {
            dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326',
           featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857',
        });
var routeCoords = route.getCoordinates();
```

Comment: `route` is a feature, not geometry, so It should be `var routeCoords = route.getGeometry().getCoordinates();`

Comment: @TomazicM It will be a geometry if it is created using `readGeometry()`.  But not all geometry types (e.g. Circle) have a `getCoordinates()` method so if using typescript a typecast to LineString would be needed.

Comment: @Mike As always :-) you are right.

Comment: @Mike how to resolve it please suggest me. thank you

Comment: @TomazicM then how to get coordinates using this code

Comment: Using the latest compiled OL it worked for me, no error.

Comment: @TomazicM  i am using latest ol - "ol": "^7.1.0", version

Comment: So do I, but compiled version https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ol@v7.1.0/dist/ol.js.

Comment: @TomazicM i am install open layers using npm.

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/13488

> A geometry can either be a `SimpleGeometry` or a `GeometryCollection`.
> TypeScript is correct, there is no `getCoordinates()` method on a `GeometryCollection`
> Before using `getCoordinates()`, make sure you're dealing with an `instanceof SimpleGeometry`.

I had a similar issue and was able to find the solution on Github's OpenLayers issue page.
Narrowing the type with "instanceof SimpleGeometry" worked for me.

```
  var routeCoords;
  if (route instanceof SimpleGeometry) {
    routeCoords = route.getCoordinates();
  }
```

However, it is necessary to be cautious because `getCoordinates()` returns `any[]` rather than `Coordinate`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import SimpleGeometry from 'ol/geom/SimpleGeometry';

(feature) => {
        let coordinates;
        const geometry = feature.getGeometry();
        if (geometry instanceof SimpleGeometry) {
          coordinates = geometry.getCoordinates();
        } else {
          // Handle GeometryCollection or other types if needed
          coordinates = [];
        }}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).